# Tailwind CSS media queries hidden

Tags: reactjs, media-queries, tailwind-css

I'm a bit confused about something that is hopefully quite simple, I'm extremely new to tailwind CSS, and even after looking into documentation I was not able to find the solution myself.

I have an image that I want visible for larger screen sizes, but hidden for smaller screen sizes.

I tried adding "sm:hidden relative" classNames to an img tag, I expected it to set the img to hidden on devices smaller than 768px.

The Opposite of what I want happens, the img shows on all devices up to 768px, but none bigger

Here is the section of my tailwind.config.cjs with media query overrides;

```
 screens: {
      xs: "480px",
      ss: "620px",
      sm: "768px",
      md: "1060px",
      lg: "1200px",
      xl: "1700px",
    },
```

My Img tag is as follows;

```
  <img src={astronaught} alt="hero-astronaught" className=" z-[5] w-[100%] h-[100%] sm:hidden relative" />
```

If I only have relative, without the sm:hidden, as expected, the img shows on all devices, if I add the above code, it shows on smaller devices, but not devices larger than 768px, I am extremely confused.

I thought that the way it works logically with sm:hidden relative was "on sm devices, it is hidden, otherwise, it is relative"

Inspecting via console shows that the media query is being applied as follows in full-screen mode;

```
@media (min-width: 768px)
<style>
.sm\:hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Inspecting via console during responsive mode for a mobile device, shows no media query at all being applied.

An important thing to note is that I have used these media queries throughout the website and they work fine for padding and margins etc.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks

Edit: If switching around the order, e.g. `hidden sm:visible` - then the image does not show on any device. If I inspect the class, it shows that the visible tag is applying, but so is the .hidden class, setting display to none

Answer (score 1):

The way that tailwind media queries work, is that e.g. doing `sm:hidden` says "for all screens equal or greater than `sm`: use `hidden`". So if you do `lg:hidden`, it counts for both `lg` and `xl` and larger, while `sm` counts for all sizes from `sm` and up.

If you want to achieve what you're describing, I'd simply do the opposite:
`hidden sm:block`.

This will make it show from `768px` and up.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply - I did try this after posting, and if I do that, the image doesn't show on any displays, if I go into inspect, I can see that 

- `@media (min-width: 768px)
<style>
.sm\:visible {
    visibility: visible;`

is being applied, but I can also see that

` .hidden {
    display: none;
}`

is also being applied, here is my img tag again with the changes

`<img src={astronaught} alt="hero-astronaught" className="z-[5] w-[100%] h-[100%]  hidden sm:visible" />`

Comment: Ah, sorry! I forgot that visibility is a different thing than display! Switch out the `sm:visible` with `sm:block`! Source: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/display#hidden

Answer (score -1):

I managed to find the solution, if I switched the classes to **invisible** sm:visible, then it worked correctly, but I want hidden, not invisible, as they work a bit differently, and so I realised that the issue was with having relative as my "opposite" to hidden. the new classes go as follows `sm:block hidden` - Thanks to Sebastion for helping me to properly understand media queries in tailwind!

Comment: Sounds like you should upvote and accepts @sebastians answer not add an answer yourself

Comment: Ah, to be fair @Liam, my answer was wrong until about half an hour ago! But at this point it should be correct.